Moving between institutions
For tenure-track assistant/associate professors that change jobs to move between institutions, do they normally get letters of recommendation from the colleagues and collaborators at their current institution? This seems to be a bit awkward, especially if the job search fails. What are the typical practices for soliciting letters in these cases?

This is a somewhat related question

Also related, potentially duplicate: How to get a "teaching letter" when I don't want my department to know I'm looking for a job? What reference from current insitution is required/advisable for pre-tenure move?

You probably need letters, especially in the US, but they don't necessarily need to come from colleagues at your institution. Other collaborators or your old advisor might be fine. But, I hope you have a few friends who will support you and keep it confidential if asked.
Many job changes are due to opportunity, not dissatisfaction, so it need not reflect badly on you if you leave. Some even leave for personal reasons, not related at all to the profession. Better climate, even.
And, "failing" in a very competitive job market isn't really a stain in any case. Relax.
